# Getting domain class values in Javascript(gsp)

Tags: javascript, grails, grails-domain-class

I want to retrieve ALL values set in my domain class to the client side (gsp or Javascript)
Let's say I have a domain class named GeneralSetting. The approach I used works but not completely how I want.

gsp file

```
<%
def test = com.domain.GeneralSetting.findAll()[0]
def test1 = com.domain.GeneralSetting.findAll()[0].color
%>
```

Js

`console.debug('${test}');`      OUTPUT: [com.domain.GeneralSetting : 1]
`console.debug('${test1}');`     OUTPUT: red

I was thinking about something like this:

```
def globalSettings = com.digithurst.gutmann.domain.GeneralSetting.getAll()[0]
def array = []

//Add all properties
 globalSettings.each {
        array.add(it);
    }
```

But when I ouput the array i just keep getting this: [com.domain.GeneralSetting : 1] instead of all the properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
<%@ page import="grails.converters.JSON" %>

<%
def test = com.domain.GeneralSetting.findAll()[0] 
def json  = test as JSON
def test1 = com.domain.GeneralSetting.findAll()[0].color
def json1  = test1 as JSON
%>
```

and js part like

```
console.debug('${json}'); 
console.debug('${json1}');
```

then

```
JSON.parse('${json}')
JSON.parse('${json1}')
```